# how to put a notification badge alongside your app launcher icon in android app using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

am trying to put a notification badge that show the number of unread messages a user has  alongside the launcher icon but am getting no luck.

Heres what am trying to archieve

[image]

Heres the code itried but dint work in  main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter_app_badger/flutter_app_badger.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:liquitech/services/notificationService.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GetStorage.init();
  await MpesaFlutterPlugin.setConsumerKey(MyConfig.mpesaConsumerKey);
  await MpesaFlutterPlugin.setConsumerSecret(MyConfig.mpesaConsumerSecret);
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ).then((value) => Get.put(AuthRepository()));

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  
   _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    _firebaseMessaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print("token:$token");
    });
  
  

  @override
  initState() {
    NotificationApi.init();
    listenNotifications();

   _firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage().then((message) async {
      final routeName = message?.data["route"];
      if (routeName != null) {
        Get.toNamed(routeName);
      }
    });

    //foreground
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      int badgeCount = int.tryParse(message.data['badge'] ?? '0') ?? 0;
      if (badgeCount > 0) {
        SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(
          ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
              label: myAppName, primaryColor: Colors.blue.value),
        );
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
          const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.blue),
        );
        _setNotificationBadge(badgeCount);
      }
      NotificationApi.showNotification(
          title: message.notification!.title,
          body: message.notification!.body,
          payload: "sarah.abs");
    });

    //background and not terminated and user taps on the notification
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      final routeName = message.data["route"];
      if (routeName != null) {
        Get.toNamed(routeName);
      }
    });
  }

  void listenNotifications() {
    NotificationApi.onNotifications.stream.listen((onClickedNotification));
  }

  void onClickedNotification(String? payload) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => const OpenedNotificationPage()));
  }

  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider(),
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: myAppName,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: isDarkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
        defaultTransition: Transition.leftToRightWithFade,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
        home: SplashScreen(myAppName: myAppName),
        getPages: [
          GetPage(
              name: "/openedNotification",
              page: () => const OpenedNotificationPage())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

   _setNotificationBadge(int badgeCount) async {
    if (badgeCount > 0) {
      await FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(badgeCount);
    } else {
      await FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
    }
  }
}
```

Itried the above code but didnt work.Please help where am doind wrong.Thank you

Iwas trying to archieve this[image]

Comment: make sure you have the necessary permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml file`.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin [flutter_app_badger](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger)  for Flutter adds the ability to change the badge of the app in the launcher. It supports iOS, macOS, and some Android devices (the official API does not support the feature, even on Oreo).